# How to get oauth2-token for Google Analytics Reporting API (REST method) in Python

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I want to route my Google Analytics Reporting API request (***code will be in AWS Lambda***) through a gateway which accepts a REST endpoint only. Since I cant use the Client package method in my interaction with the gateway, I need to query the API as a REST-ful endpoint.

The official document says this ([Link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference)) :

```
Authorization: Bearer {oauth2-token}

GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga
  ?ids=ga:12345
  &start-date=2008-10-01
  &end-date=2008-10-31
  &metrics=ga:sessions,ga:bounces
```

I do not know to create the oauth2-token in Python. I have created a service account and have the secrets_json which includes the client id and secret key.
Then client package method as given in this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py) works. But I need the Rest method only!

Using these, how can I create the oauth2-token ?

Comment: If you are going to use a service account i recommend that you use the client library. If you cant then i suggest you try and pick it apart the client library and find the code they are using.  This may help as well https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount  I wish you luck.   Service account authentication is not a simple thing like oauth2

Comment: @DaImTo  Any other way if I don't use service account ?

Comment: use Oauth2 and authenticate it once and save the refresh token and use that whenever you need a new access token

Comment: @DaImTo I understand that but how exactly do I do that ? Can you provide a sample code? This ispart of a script that means to automate the process. So no manual user authentication.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Oauth2 for this I have done it in the past but you will need to monitor it.  You will need to authorize this code once and save the refresh token. Refresh tokens are long lived they normally dont expire but your code should be able to contact you if it does so that you can authorize it again.   If you save the refresh token you can use the last step at any time to request a new access token.

Oauth2 is basicly built up into three calls.  I can give you the HTTP calls i will let you work out the Python [Google 3 Legged OAuth2 Flow](https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

**Authencation and authorization**

The first thing you need is the permission of the user.  To get that you build a link on the authorization server.  This is a HTTP get request you can place it in a normal browser window to test it.

```
GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code
```

Note on redirect uri. If you are running this on a server or something then use `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` it basicly tells the server to return the code back where it came from other wise if you are hosing on a website you can supply a url to the page that will be handling the response.

If the user accepts the above then you will have an authorization code.

**Exchange code**

What you need to do next is exchange the authorization code returned by the above response and request an access token and a refresh token.  THis is a http post call

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

The body parameter should be as i have shown separated by & and the content type of the request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Responce

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4"
}
```

The access token can be used in all of your requests to the api by adding either an authorization header bearer token with the access token or by sending access_token= as your parameter in your requests.

**Refresh access token**

Refresh tokens are long lived they should not expire they can so you code should be able to handle that but normally they are good forever.   Access tokens are only valid for one hour and you will need to request a new access token.

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

response

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_XK16As2ZHlScqOxGtntIlevNcasMSPwGiE3pe5ANZfrmJTcsI3ZtAjv4sDrPDRnQ",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600
}
```